# Nostalgia for the future

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word to describe my feelings for a special place and time that cannot last. Specifically I seek a word to describe what I call a nostalgia for the future - the sentiment I would have if I live to see the loss of that which I find very special. In my case it is the beauty of the place and time in which I live: mountains, ocean, forests, birds and other wildlife, but I suspect many of us have this future nostalgic sense. Is there a word for this? If not, perhaps one can be invented.

Thank you.

Comment: Won't you call it 'anxiety'? A child scared of losing his mother has 'separation anxiety'

Comment: It would be nostalgia when it kicked in. It may never happen. As Jony implies, it's a fear of loss.

Comment: @David Farmer: reminds of these lyrics: "The remembrance of today is the sad feeling of tomorrow".

Comment: The word "fleeting" has connotations of nostalgia and limited time.

Answer (score 3):

I think "saudade" might be the work you are looking for.
Reference : [Wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saudade)

Comment: The word applies to the feeling that confronts something lost.  The OP hasn't lost his precious yet.

Comment: @deadrat I meant more like "sadly accepting of fate(loss) " . .The sentiment is "he admired the beauty & going to miss it sadly"

Comment: The OP would feel *saudade* after the loss occurs.  He wants a word for the feeling now that anticipates the future *saudade*.

Comment: it is meant for both "feeling of loss towards the past or the future.."..please check the refernced link.

Comment: I checked your link.  It says nothing about the future.  Only about a longing for something this is missed, absent already.

Comment: @deadrat did you searched for "future" ??

Comment: I missed it.  The descriptions (if not translations) in this source and the others I found are almost always about a loss sustained, but you're right.  So that deserves an upvote.

Comment: Please edit your post to follow our [Help Center's guidelines on how to reference other sites](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). It is not sufficient to include merely a link, because the source of the quotation must be able to survive a plain-text (or plain-paper) transformation intact without loss of information explaining who said it and where it's from.

Answer (score 1):

**Angst** is a bit too strong, but it seems it could still work, at least with a qualifier.

So let me suggest **bittersweet angst**. This might capture the feeling.

Consider:

> Cameron, and Sloane wrestle with questions of parental pressure,
>   societal conformity, and the **bittersweet angst** that flavors the
>   last few weeks of high school, when **you know that unstoppable change
>   is right around the corner.**

([Book source](https://books.google.com/books?id=XawD2yexM_kC&pg=PA176&lpg=PA176&dq=%22bittersweet%20angst%22&source=bl&ots=IxjcJe-uE0&sig=rImopbEhAip6M825zAYS0wgIUDY&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false))

Answer (score -1):

*Insecurity* would be the word you are looking for.